# Can't access package scoped field of depend plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a plugin A which exports the package foo.bar. In the package foo.bar there is a abstract class FooBar with default scope members. In a plugin B I like to extend the FooBar within the same package and access the default scoped fields.

Plugin A manifest:

```
.
Bundle-SymbolicName: A    
Export-Package: foo.bar
.
```

Plugin B manifest:

```
.
Bundle-SymbolicName: B    
Require-Bundle: A
.
```

Class FooBar in Plugin A:

```
package foo.bar;

public abstract class FooBar{
  int min = -1;
}
```

Class MyFooBar in Plugin B:

```
package foo.bar;

public class MyFooBar extends FooBar{
  public void setMin(int min){
   this.min = min;
  }
}
```

The result:
..Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field foo.bar.FooBar.min from class foo.bar.MyFooBar

In a normal java environment I can access package-scoped members if I define my class in the same package. Apparently this is not so in OSGI-Environment, is it??

Comment: Is the Bundle-SymbolicName for Plugin B really "A"? Duplicate names can cause odd behaviour

Comment: Thanks for the information to Simon and Fredrik. My problem is I extended the log4j-Framework about a pattern-class which extends the the PatternConverter few years ago. And now I have to port it to eclipse-bundles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make the bundle B a fragment for A (if it is possible in your case). Than B can access *package-private* classes because there is the same package name and class loader.

Read the following article [Split Packages – An OSGi nightmare](http://nirmalsasidharan.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/split-packages-an-osgi-nightmare/) - it explains the problem in clear way.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, OSGI plugins aren't the same as java packages. If you truly want to share the same `min` value in both plugins, the best option is to share it through extension points. Extension points are the OSGI way to share data and code between plugins. This leads to a solution that doesnt cause a tight coupling between the plugins.

If plugin B truly must access the `min` value in plugin A that might be an indication that those two classes should be in the same plugin.

Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457117/global-variables-in-eclipse-rcp)

More information about extension points can be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html)

Comment: See my comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse plug-ins / OSGi bundles each have their own separate classloaders (and thus namespaces). Package private means same package and classloader.

Comment: See my comment under the question.